# Nifi convertRecord CSV to JSON truncate number values

Tags: apache-nifi

I have the following CSV file in entry and I convert CSV to JSON using a convertRecord with csvReader and JsonRecordSetWriter

```
key,x,y,latitude,longitude
123,722052.172555174,6555555.17858555,42.0422004518503,2.21755344237117
```

but my float values are truncated

```
{"key":123,"x":722052.2,"y":6555555.0,"latitude":42.042202,"longitude":2.2175534}
```

How to get them all without truncating them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to achieve that with an explicit schema (CSV Reader service):

- `Schema Access Strategy`: `Use 'Schema Text' Property`
- `Schema Text`:

```json
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "MyClass",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "key",
    "type" : "long"
  }, {
    "name" : "x",
    "type" : "double"
  }, {
    "name" : "y",
    "type" : "double"
  }, {
    "name" : "latitude",
    "type" : "double"
  }, {
    "name" : "longitude",
    "type" : "double"
  } ]
}
```

Output JSON with explicit schema:

```json
{
  "key" : 123,
  "x" : 722052.172555174,
  "y" : 6555555.17858555,
  "latitude" : 42.0422004518503,
  "longitude" : 2.21755344237117
}
```